# Is possible to sellect the name of AncestorType in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ancestor

I have more than one listbox in my XAML. Before I have this code below:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Rectangle" Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
```

Is possible to reference on my other ListBox? I name my second listbox so:

```
x:Name="HappyBox"
```

How to change upper line of code to reference only the ListBox with name "HappyBox"

If any question please ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have your control named, you dont have to specify type by using `AncestorType`, you can just use `ElementName`.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=HappyBox}" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="Rectangle" Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Like that

Comment: My problem is also that I have ListBox in other NameScope, so I cannot find my HappyBox in ElementName. Is any solution there? How to obtain this?

Comment: But you have that `HappyBox` in parents of your control in VisualTree, right?

Comment: No:) I update my code. So I have two listbox - one is x:Name="LstBox" and second "SldBox". Somewhere there is "local: SliderNode". In "local: SliderNode" I have defined "AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}". I dont have defined all ListBoxItems but just SldBox. I will solve this whit parent child relationship?